# Ambiguous type variable 'blah' in the constraint... how to fix?

Tags: haskell, type-variables

I'm trying to write a simple ray-tracer in Haskell. I wanted to define a typeclass representing the various kinds of surfaces available, with a function to determine where a ray intersects them:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

data Vector = Vector Double Double Double
data Ray = Ray Vector Vector

class Surface s where
  intersections :: s -> Ray -> [Vector]

-- Obviously there would be some concrete surface implementations here...

data Renderable = Renderable
  { surface    :: (Surface s) => s
  , otherStuff :: Int
  }

getRenderableIntersections :: Renderable -> Ray -> [Vector]
getRenderableIntersections re ra = intersections (surface re) ra
```

However this gives me the error:

```
Ambiguous type variable 's' in the constraint:
  'Surface'
    arising from a use of 'surface'
```

*(The actual code is more complex but I've tried to distill it to something simpler, while keeping the gist of what I'm trying to achieve).*

How do I fix this? Or alternatively, given that I come from a standard OO background, what am I fundamentally doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please don't use existential types for this! You could, but there would be no point.

From a functional standpoint you can drop this typeclass notion of Surface entirely. A `Surface` is something that maps a Ray to a list of Vectors, no? So:

```
type Surface = Ray -> [Vector]

data Renderable = Renderable
 { surface    :: Surface
 , otherStuff :: Int
}
```

Now if you really want, you can have a `ToSurface` typeclass essentially as you gave:

```
class ToSurface a where
     toSurface :: a -> Surface
```

But that's just for convenience and ad-hoc polymorphism. Nothing in your model requires it.

In general, there are a very few use cases for existentials, but at least 90% of the time you can substitute an existential with the functions it represents and obtain something cleaner and easier to reason about.

Also, even though it may be a tad too much for you to take in, and the issues don't exactly match, you might find useful some of Conal's writing on denotational design: http://conal.net/blog/posts/thoughts-on-semantics-for-3d-graphics/

Answer (score 3):

In your `getRenderableIntersections` function you call `surface`. There is no way for the interpreter to figure out what instance of the class `Surface` you want to use. If you have two such instances:

```
instance Surface SurfaceA where
  -- ...
instance Surface SurfaceB where
  -- ...
```

How can the interpreter determine the type of `surface`?

The way you defined `Renderable` means there is a function `surface :: Surface s => Renderable -> s`.

Try creating an instance `Surface SurfaceA` and asking the following type query (given a simple constructor `SurfaceA`):

```
> :t surface (Renderable SurfaceA 0) -- What's the type of the expression?
```

So, what type is this expression? I bet you're expecting `SurfaceA`. Wrong. Take the type of `surface`. It takes a `Renderable` argument and we're passing it a `Renderable` argument. What is left after that? `Surface s => s`. That's the type of that expression. We still don't know what type does `s` represent.

If you want the type to be `SurfaceA` you need to change your code so it becomes something like `surface :: Surface s => Renderable s -> s`. This way what `s` is can be determined, because it is the same `s` used in `Renderable`.

EDIT: As suggested by @mokus, you could also try the [`ExistentialTypes`](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Existential_types) extension. It allows "hiding" away type parameters on the right side of a type declaration.

```
data Renderable = forall s. Surface s => Renderable
  { surface    :: s
  , otherStuff :: Int
  }
```

The HaskellWiki page I linked to above even has [an example](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Existential_types#Expanded_example_-_rendering_objects_in_a_raytracer) very similar to what you want to do.

**EDIT: (By @stusmith)** - For the record, I'm including code below which compiles based on these suggestions here. However I've accepted the answer which I think shows a better way of approaching things.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

data Vector = Vector Double Double Double
data Ray = Ray Vector Vector

class Surface_ s where
  intersections :: s -> Ray -> [Vector]

data Surface = forall s. Surface_ s => Surface s

instance Surface_ Surface where
  intersections (Surface s) ra = intersections s ra

data Renderable = Renderable
  { surface :: Surface
  }

getRenderableIntersections :: Renderable -> Ray -> [Vector]
getRenderableIntersections re ra = intersections (surface re) ra
```

Comment: ...but since all surfaces implement the 'intersections' method, why isn't that enough? Obviously with my background I'm seeing 'Surface' as an abstract class, and 'intersections' as a virtual method.

Comment: @stusmith: see my update. You cannot have open type parameters in the middle of expressions. Either the entire expression is parametric, or the types can all be determined statically. (Maybe there is a GHC extension or something that allows that, but I don't know it)

Comment: So does this mean that Haskell doesn't have the equivalent of 'virtual' functions? I wanted to have a list of Renderables, and to be able to work on them as abstract types. Do I therefore need to have `[Renderable s]` instead? And can that list contain heterogenous `Renderable` instances with different `Surface` instances?

Comment: @stusmith: The type of the `surface` field is not what you're expecting.  It is `forall s. Surface s => s`, so values in that field must be valid values of _every_ `Surface` type.  The only possible such value is `undefined` and the like (since the `Surface` class defines no functions that yield `s`).  What you're looking for is the `ExistentialTypes` extension, not `RankNTypes`, and the `Surface s =>` context would go before the data constructor, i.e. `data Renderable = forall s. Surface s => Renderable ...` if I'm remembering the syntax correctly.  That should be enough to google anyway ;)

Comment: @mokus: thanks for chiming in with the name of the extension.